# Research supervisor is easily distracted in meetings with me

Tags: professorship, research-undergraduate, lab-meeting

I don't think my research professor takes me seriously. I have noticed that in several of my meetings with my PI, he gets distracted very easily.

Now I know of people my age who get distracted (in their 20s), but he insists it's something natural... and he's way older. For example at our last meeting, he was advising me on what I should do for the next part of my project, I was writing all that stuff down, and then he spaced off. I was looking through my notes to see if I understood everything correctly, and he stared up at the ceiling. Next, he asked me if I knew what the ceiling material consisted of. When I said I had no idea (I was trying to brush off the question because there are more important tasks at hand), he made me look it up on the spot. At the moment I thought he might have become bored, maybe there was an awkward silence, but now that I've been thinking about it more, this is not the first instance where this has occurred. He does this in front of my other classmates as well.

Is he just joking around? Trying to lighten up the mood? Am I awkward? Am I not important? How do I address this to him?

Comment: "He does this in front of my other classmates as well" - he gets distracted when he and I chat about my project, while other students are around.

Comment: It sounds like he has an attention problem. There doesn't seem to be any indication that it's about _you_.

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a question here that we can answer for you (we don't know him). Just sounds like an attention issue or something else psychological. I've had meetings with people that had far worse issues. Learn how to work with it.

Comment: @ff524 is right.  Attention problems are less common in older people but they are not rare.  Also, any professor will have attention problems at a 4 PM meeting if they have been working since 6 AM.  Or if they worked until 6 AM.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - good point.  Then the question still is, how do these two people figure out how to work together comfortably and productively?

Comment: So, what was the ceiling made of?

Comment: Why was this question closed?  I'm not saying it should or shouldn't be, I'm just surprised there was no explanation given.

Answer (score 2):

Most people can concentrate better when they are still fresh, so my suggestion is try to schedule a meeting with him early in the morning, or as early as possible. Like the other answer has suggested, try to keep the meeting as compact as possible. Also, you might also have to try to keep him occupied on you so that he don't have any time to start thinking of something else. This can be done by keeping the discussion on. You have to learn to write while thinking and talking at the same time.

Answer (score -4):

I have a few practical suggestions for you, to cope with your advisor's distractibility.

- Set the scene.  For example, if squirrels or interesting people outside his office window are drawing his attention, tell him the light bothers you and ask permission to lower the blinds.  If he gets mesmerized by his screen saver, ask if it would be okay to turn off the monitor, or position yourself so that his back will be to his monitor.  Etc.
- Ask permission to tape record your meetings.  Write down your notes later.  Keep things moving in your meetings, so that he doesn't have a chance to get too interested in the ceiling.
- Bring along a couple of quiet fidget items, and put them in on the edge of the desk or table, where you can both reach them.  For example, one of the modern forms of silly putty.  The little donkey who takes a bow when you push up on the base.  Etc.
- Observe how many minutes it takes for him to get distracted, subtract 5, and try to wrap up your meetings in that many minutes.
- Have some of your conversations while on a small hike together.
- Give him a yoga ball as a gift, for sitting and bouncing in his office.  Tell him you heard it's recommended for optimal back health and concentration.
- Observe what time of day seems to work best, and schedule your meetings accordingly.
- Bring along a high-protein snack to share.
- Allow yourselves a 25% failure rate.  Be philosophical about it.  As mentioned in a comment -- don't take it personally.

I have experience collaborating with people with ADD and ADHD. Not all of the above ideas are guaranteed to be helpful with any individual distractible person.  Experiment.

Comment: I'm not sure all these suggestions are appropriate for an advisor/advisee relationship.  Maybe you should add why you think these will work.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist - I can say why I think they *might* work.  Because the advisor is a distractible person who is nevertheless capable of good work, no?  So with the right environmental accommodations, he should be capable of doing good advising, too.  //  All my suggestions came from living with a distractible person.  The idea is, see what the student can tweak, so as to get the best out of the advisor.

Comment: I understand that you like to talk about the things you do for your son. He's very fortunate that you invest all these efforts to take care of him. This being said, this situation has **nothing** to do with you taking care of your son. I'm sure you know of support forums for parents where that kind of content might be helpful. Bringing a puppet monkey to a meeting with one's advisor is rubbish advice.

Comment: @CapeCode - Puppet monkey?  Do you mean the donkey fidget?  Hmm.  Have you ever tried making a fidget available to a person like OP's advisor?

Comment: Puppet donkey then. "yoga ball" and "high protein snack to share" are equally silly ideas. This is two professionals meeting to talk work.

Comment: @CapeCode - Pardon the question, but have you ever tried to work closely with someone with ADD or ADHD?  If you have, and have some better ideas to try, I would be very glad to hear them.  //  Note, my list was offered in the spirit of brainstorming.  I do not mean to say that everything on the list will work in all cases.

Comment: It is a parent's job to care for their children and help them deal with  AD(H)D. It is **not** a student's job to care for their advisor or help them  deal with AD(H)D.  The advisor is an adult professional; they are responsible for their own treatment and behavior.

Comment: Also, **nobody here even knows** if that person has any kind of attention disorder.

Comment: @aparente001 I might very well have, how would I know? I don't ask medical records of people I work with. Even if I had, I wouldn't be giving advice here for many reasons, the most straightforward one is that it would be completely off topic on this site.

Comment: @CapeCode - Sorry.  I should have said, have you ever tried to work closely with someone who is very distractible.

Comment: @JeffE, It used to be thought that children with ADD outgrow it when they reach adulthood. It is true that as the brain matures, things can get better; also, as the person gains experience, he (hopefully) gets better at using coping mechanisms. At any rate, the bottom line here is that the OP could (a) take it personally and feel offended, (b) try to sand with the grain, so to speak, to get the most out of this advisor, or (c) choose a different advisor. I am not recommending against (c) -- that is a very personal choice. My answer is, if OP wants to do (b), here are some ideas to start with.